# How to perform socket activation, passing a socket to a child proc as stdin/out, in golang?

Tags: linux, go, network-programming, posix

I have a C program that runs via systemd socket activation. Systemd listens on a port and when a TCP connections comes in, then the application is launched and it treats stdin/stdout **exactly like** a socket (IE: setsockopt, etc) .

I am trying to mimic this behavior with a small launching program in go. It will just be told what port to listen on and what command to run when a connection is made to it (none of the other advanced systemd features).

The problem I am having is that I don't seem to be able to pass the connection as a socket to stdin/out. Passing the TCPConn to `Stdin` and `Stdout` of the `Cmd` did not work (the C program errored on setsockopts).

```golang
            cmd := exec.Cmd{
                Path:   cmds,
                Args:   args,
                Stdin:  conn.,
                Stdout: conn,
                Stderr: os.Stderr,
            }
            err = cmd.Run()
```

I saw an [article](https://www6.uniovi.es/cscene/CS5/CS5-05.html) on how to do something like this in C using `dup(2)` and fork, but

- it is forking not exec-ing another child process
- I don't entirely understand with the socket fd is being duplicated and not the `client` accepted connection

Is there any way to do something like this in Golang?

### aditional info

the socket file looks roughly like

```
[Unit]
Description=soc activated program 

[Socket]
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:10101
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

and corresponding unit file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Program 

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myprog -N
StandardInput=socket
StandardOutput=socket
StandardError=journal
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the connections's [file](https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPConn.File):

```
        f, err := conn.File()
        if err != nil { /* TODO handle error */}
        defer f.Close()

        cmd := exec.Cmd{
            Path:   cmds,
            Args:   args,
            Stdin:  f,
            Stdout: f,
            Stderr: os.Stderr,
        }
        err = cmd.Run()
```